# capture event if drop-drop has been done on the HTML page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, drag-and-drop

I work on Angular4 and 5 and I have a functionality to upload a file in the table. So, on click of an `Add` button a pop-up will appear and through that pop-up we can browse or drag-drop a file/files.

My requirement is as soon as the drag-drop/browse is done I have to make a service call. So is there any way I can capture an event if the files has been browsed/drag-droppped? If so please guide me. IS there any other way I can achieve this?

PS: This upload pop-up and the Add button is 3rd party, I cannot make any change in their component/HTML. The thing I am trying to do is to capture the event, if there is any other way please suggest.

HTML

```
<button>Add Files</button>
<3rd-party-upload-popup></3rd-party-upload-popup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make a plunker for the same, specifying where actually you need the event. Otherwise what i understood is that when you drop something, you may require an event. For this in Angular drop event is there. Also you may want to look at [sortableJs](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs)

Comment: plunker is not allowed in my organization, and yes your understanding is correct when I drop something I require an event

Comment: then you might just want to use the drop event in angular. Something like 

<div
class="input-upload"
*ngIf="status != 'finished'"
(drop)="onDrop($event)"
(dragenter)="dragenter()"
(dragleave)="dragleave()"
(dragover)="dragover()"
>

But make sure that you use event.preventDefault() in your calling method, otherwise event will propagate and may cause some issue for you.